# Missing Argument in for multiple __construct

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

I use multiple construct from this site.

I modified it for my needs.

I get fatal errors:

```
Missing argument 3 for ChildClass::__construct2()
```

and chained errors...

```
Missing argument 4 for ChildClass::__construct2() 
Missing argument 5 for ChildClass::__construct2() 
Undefined variable: c 
Undefined variable: d
```

And both constructors have part of identical code. How can I put it in common __construct.

```
$arr = array (
    "key1" => "val1",
    "key2" => "val2"
);

$demo = new Demo("stack", $arr );

class ParentClass {
    function __construct($var1 = "1", $var2 = "2"){
        // distinctly different code
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    function __construct(){     
        $a = func_get_args(); 
        $i = func_num_args(); 
        if (method_exists($this,$f='__construct'.$i)) { 
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$f),$a); 
        }
    }

    function __construct1( $a, array $e ) {
        $this->ex = $a;

        $this->ex3 = $e['key1'];
        $this->ex4 = $e['key2'];
    }

    function __construct2( $a, $b, $c, $d, array $e ) {
        $this->ex = $a + 1 - $v + $c; //example
        $this->ex2 = $d;

        $this->ex3 = $e['key1'];
        $this->ex4 = $e['key2'];
    }
}
```

And both constructors have part of identical code. How can I put it in common __construct.

thanks.

Comment: Your `ChildClass` constructor is invalid: It breaks the inherited contract. Also don't use the `__` prefix in your own method names, they're meant to be used _only_ for magic methods (constructor, destructor, setters, getters, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number specified after __construct tells how many parameter it will except . You specified 2 after __construct but you are giving it 5 parameters because of which it is giving the error. Change 2 to 5.Also rename __construct1 to __construct2 Use the code below

```
$arr = array (
    "key1" => "val1",
    "key2" => "val2"
);

$demo = new Demo("stack", $arr );

class ParentClass {
    function __construct($var1 = "1", $var2 = "2"){
        // distinctly different code
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    function __construct(){     
        $a = func_get_args(); 
        $i = func_num_args(); 
        if (method_exists($this,$f='__construct'.$i)) { 
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$f),$a); 
        }
    }

function __construct2( $a, array $e ) { 
    $this->ex = $a;

    $this->setE($e);
}
    function __construct5( $a, $b, $c, $d, array $e ) {
        $this->ex = $a + 1 - $v + $c; //example
        $this->ex2 = $d;

        $this->ex3 = $e['key1'];
        $this->ex4 = $e['key2'];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks. Now I can't refer to this->ex in my code Notice: Undefined property: ChildClass::$ex

Comment: @user3679891 Updated my answer have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

It's because the 2 in `__construct2` tells it expects 2 parameters, but it expects 5. Change the name to `__construct5`.

To put the identical code to one place, make it separate method that will be called from both constructors, full code:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    function __construct(){     
        $a = func_get_args(); 
        $i = func_num_args(); 
        if (method_exists($this,$f='__construct'.$i)) { 
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$f),$a); 
        }
    }

    function __construct2( $a, array $e ) { // rename method: 1 => 2
        $this->ex = $a;

        $this->setE($e);
    }

    function __construct5( $a, $b, $c, $d, array $e ) { // rename method: 2 => 5
        $this->ex = $a + 1 - $v + $c; //example
        $this->ex2 = $d;

        $this->setE($e);
    }

    private function setE(array $e) {
        $this->ex3 = $e['key1'];
        $this->ex4 = $e['key2'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was inattentive.